# Integrate Amazon API Gateway with Amazon EKS

Tags: aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk, ingress-controller

I'm integrating the API Gate with EKS, using CDK
Following this architecture as below
[image]

I'm using the ALB Controller which provisions a NLB when I deploy an k8s service with type LoadBalancer

The problem is, how can I aware when the NLB will be provisioned, how to get its "object reference" then connect it to a VPC link for API gateway resources to access?

Can you please help for a CDK sample?

Comment: i had the same problem bro, did you get it?

Comment: i did bro, but in two steps, first deploy the alb and then print the output with cnf and then deploy the api gateway with the vpc link connection, and the arn i create a function to get it from the balancer url.